# How to retain the background color of selected item in list view?

Tags: java, android

I am having a listview and edittext in an activity. On selection of an item in 
the list view I am able to change its background to diff color using 
'android:listselector'. Now, I move to edit text. Immediately on my move to edit 
text the background color of the selected item in the list view changes to 
default. How to prevent this?

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="129dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:listSelector="#666666"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button7"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
   android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:padding="-11dp"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textSize="34sp"
    android:editable="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="163dp"
    android:hint="$" />
```

Comment: You are using custom adapter means custom layout ?

Comment: Using simplecursoradapter and customlayout for the listview.:

Comment: thislist.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.outlistview_customshape);

Comment: Actually in custom layout you have to set the background to selected row and it will remain selected .

Comment: I tried like this, but not helping:

Comment: android:background="@drawable/outlistview_customshape"/>      <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF00FF00" />
    <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="1dp"
        android:right="7dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
</shape>

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Category_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

//initialize selectedposition
    private int selectedPosition = -1;


    public Category_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Category_Items> items,
            String show) {
        this.context = context;


            this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (view == null) {

            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_titles_n_sellers_list,
                    parent, false);


        //Set Background to the selected position 
            if (position == selectedPosition) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.orange_list));
                // view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFA500"));

            } else {
                view.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(
                        R.color.white));
                // view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            }


        return view;
    }

//get the selected position from activtiy
    public void setSelected(int position) {
        selectedPosition = position;
    }

}
```

Now in activity class :

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // set the custom adapter method and set the selectedposition with the listview position
        ((Category_Adapter) adapter).setSelected(position);


    }
```

Try this, for me it worked.

Comment: Actually I am able to set the background color for single item selected. Next, if I go to edittext the keyboard pops up and when I start entering data, the background color in the list box selected item disappears.

Comment: for that may be you have to put the logic inside when edittext is focused and set the background again to the selected position or call the function from custom adapter.